# How can I draw $f(S)$ with $f(z)=z^{1+i}$ where $S=\{0<Arg(z)<\pi/6\}$?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, logarithms, exponential-function

> Let $f:\Bbb{C}\setminus(-\infty, 0]\rightarrow \Bbb{C}$ where $f(z)=z^{1+i}:=e^{(1+i)\log(z)}$.  We consider $$S=\{0<Arg(z)<\pi/6\}$$
> I want to draw $f(S)$.

If I take $z\in S$ then $z=re^{it}$ where $r\in [0,\infty)$ and $t\in (0,\pi/6)$. Then $\log(z)=\log(r)+it$ where now $\log(r)\in (-\infty, \infty)$. Then $$f(z)=e^{\log(r)-t}e^{i(\log(r)+t)}=:r'e^{it'}$$ where $$r'=e^{\log(r)-t}~~~t'=\log(r)+t$$But now I don't see how to proceed so how one could really draw the curve from here?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have that , $$0<r < \infty \\ 0 < t < \frac{\pi}{6}$$

Essentially, we want to find the bound on $r'$ and $t'$, for the $t'$ suppose fix some $t$ and you varying $r$, you should be able to get every single value of $t'$ similarly for $r'$.

Seems so that this function maps the sector to the whole plane.

Comment: May have mistake. Let me know if there are errors and I will revise the answer.

Comment: The function $e^z$ isn't surjective.

Comment: I guess you map into the whole plane excluding the origin, is that correct? @Cpc

Comment: Not sure.   But the image doesn't include the origin.